# Pandas Grouper - Specify End Date Which Has No Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of daily values like this:

```
        orderdate                   id      total   noitems dt
4241    2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  30266   19.95   1   2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304
4244    2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  30269   34.91   2   2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482
4246    2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  30271   19.95   1   2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225
4249    2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  30274   49.88   3   2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141
4250    2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  30275   19.95   1   2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492
4251    2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  30276   19.95   1   2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376
4254    2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  30279   49.88   3   2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686
```

I'm running a daily grouper to get the totals per day like this:

```
t1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="1D")).agg(no_orders=('id', 'count'), order_value=('total', 'sum'), no_reports=('noitems', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

Which gives me this:

```
    dt          no_orders  order_value  no_reports
0   2021-02-21  4          139.68        7
1   2021-02-22  2          54.86         3
2   2021-02-23  1          49.88         3
3   2021-02-24  2          39.90         2
4   2021-02-25  1          49.88         3
```

Today's date is 2021-02-26 and I don't have any orders yet.  How can I get the grouper to include the final date like this:

```
5   2021-02-26  0          0.00          0
```

without doing a hack like adding a dummy row to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If datetimes are consecutive you can add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by minimal and custom maximal by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) after `groupby`:

```
df = (t1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="1D"))
        .agg(no_orders=('id', 'count'), 
             order_value=('total', 'sum'), 
             no_reports=('noitems', 'sum')))

df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), '2021-02-26'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
       index  no_orders  order_value  no_reports
0 2021-02-21          1        19.95           1
1 2021-02-22          2        54.86           3
2 2021-02-23          1        49.88           3
3 2021-02-24          2        39.90           2
4 2021-02-25          1        49.88           3
5 2021-02-26          0         0.00           0
```

---

You can add new DataFrame before `groupby` filled only by `dt`, so after [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) all columns are filled by `NaN`s:

```
t1 = t1.append(pd.DataFrame({'dt':[pd.to_datetime('2021-02-26')]}))

print (t1)
                      orderdate       id  total  noitems  \
4241 2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  30266.0  19.95      1.0   
4244 2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  30269.0  34.91      2.0   
4246 2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  30271.0  19.95      1.0   
4249 2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  30274.0  49.88      3.0   
4250 2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  30275.0  19.95      1.0   
4251 2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  30276.0  19.95      1.0   
4254 2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  30279.0  49.88      3.0   
0                           NaT      NaN    NaN      NaN   

                             dt  
4241 2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  
4244 2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  
4246 2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  
4249 2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  
4250 2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  
4251 2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  
4254 2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  
0    2021-02-26 00:00:00.000000
```

---

```
df = (t1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="1D"))
        .agg(no_orders=('id', 'count'), 
             order_value=('total', 'sum'), 
             no_reports=('noitems', 'sum'))
        .reset_index())


print (df)
          dt  no_orders  order_value  no_reports
0 2021-02-21          1        19.95         1.0
1 2021-02-22          2        54.86         3.0
2 2021-02-23          1        49.88         3.0
3 2021-02-24          2        39.90         2.0
4 2021-02-25          1        49.88         3.0
5 2021-02-26          0         0.00         0.0
```

Advantage of missing values is if aggregate them by `sum` get `0` and for `count` get also `0`, because it exclude missing values in count. So if add new row with data for `2021-02-26` then output is rewritten by new data (NaNs values are not count).

```
print (t1)
                       orderdate     id  total  noitems  \
4241  2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  30266  19.95        1   
4244  2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  30269  34.91        2   
4246  2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  30271  19.95        1   
4249  2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  30274  49.88        3   
4250  2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  30275  19.95        1   
4251  2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  30276  19.95        1   
4254  2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  30279  49.88        3   
4255  2021-02-26 15:21:11.905304  30266  19.95        1  <- exist data for 2021-02-26


                              dt  
4241  2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  
4244  2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  
4246  2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  
4249  2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  
4250  2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  
4251  2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  
4254  2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  
4255  2021-02-26 15:21:11.905304
```

---

```
t1 = t1.append(pd.DataFrame({'dt':[pd.to_datetime('2021-02-26')]}))
print (t1)
                      orderdate       id  total  noitems  \
4241 2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  30266.0  19.95      1.0   
4244 2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  30269.0  34.91      2.0   
4246 2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  30271.0  19.95      1.0   
4249 2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  30274.0  49.88      3.0   
4250 2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  30275.0  19.95      1.0   
4251 2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  30276.0  19.95      1.0   
4254 2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  30279.0  49.88      3.0   
4255 2021-02-26 15:21:11.905304  30266.0  19.95      1.0 <- exist data for 2021-02-26 
0                           NaT      NaN    NaN      NaN <- added NaNs data for  2021-02-26

                             dt  
4241 2021-02-21 15:21:11.905304  
4244 2021-02-22 03:17:17.666482  
4246 2021-02-22 22:48:06.177225  
4249 2021-02-23 23:27:54.544141  
4250 2021-02-24 12:44:20.693492  
4251 2021-02-24 13:45:27.901376  
4254 2021-02-25 00:37:16.138686  
4255 2021-02-26 15:21:11.905304  
0    2021-02-26 00:00:00.000000
```

---

```
df = (t1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="1D"))
        .agg(no_orders=('id', 'count'), 
             order_value=('total', 'sum'), 
             no_reports=('noitems', 'sum'))
        .reset_index())


print (df)


          dt  no_orders  order_value  no_reports
0 2021-02-21          1        19.95         1.0
1 2021-02-22          2        54.86         3.0
2 2021-02-23          1        49.88         3.0
3 2021-02-24          2        39.90         2.0
4 2021-02-25          1        49.88         3.0
5 2021-02-26          1        19.95         1.0 <-NaNs data for 2021-02-26 are overwritten
```

If need today datetime:

```
t1 = t1.append(pd.DataFrame({'dt':[pd.to_datetime('now')]}))

df = (t1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="dt", freq="1D"))
        .agg(no_orders=('id', 'count'), 
             order_value=('total', 'sum'), 
             no_reports=('noitems', 'sum'))
        .reset_index())


print (df)
          dt  no_orders  order_value  no_reports
0 2021-02-21          1        19.95         1.0
1 2021-02-22          2        54.86         3.0
2 2021-02-23          1        49.88         3.0
3 2021-02-24          2        39.90         2.0
4 2021-02-25          1        49.88         3.0
5 2021-02-26          0         0.00         0.0
6 2021-02-27          0         0.00         0.0
7 2021-02-28          0         0.00         0.0
8 2021-03-01          0         0.00         0.0
```

Comment: Well, similar to adding a dummy row, but at least it works. ;-)   Thanks.

Comment: @blissweb - I add new solution in first paragraph.